# Processing Resources with error: Wrong Parameter

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors

I'm developing with Visual Studio 2013. 
Target is a multilingual C# Windows Phone project. I've been working for it quite some time and added SQLite support yesterday (and changed `Platform Target` to `ARM`). After that it was still compiling and running on my Smartphone.

However today I merely changed anything that I could think could be of any harm (some minor changes in functions and translation), but I got the following Error message:

[image]

```
Processing Resources with error: Wrong Parameter. 
Unspecified error occurred.
```

I tried some things:

- `MAKEPRI dump /if resources.pri /of resources.xml` with VC2013 Prompt, looks like a normal Resource file to me, like I would edit it.
- `Verbose` in Build Options gave me a 2k line build log. I copied out the sections, where it says 'failed':

  ```
  1>Done executing task "GenerateProjectPriFile" -- FAILED. (TaskId:143)
  1>Done building target "_GenerateProjectPriFileCore" in project "myproject.csproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:98)
  ```

I have honestly no idea what to do about it. It just doesn't compile anymore. Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you ensured that the target directory is fully writable for your user account? Please could you Pastebin your build log under `Verbose` and paste the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this is very odd.

The solution was simpler than expected. I added the `resources.resx` file to a new project and became the same error, so I suspected that something is wrong with my file.
After carefully deleting one line by another and compiling, I finally had the mistake.

One line was saying

```
<data name="TestCalculation_TBox_TestCalculate..PlaceholderText" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Calculate value one</value>
</data>
```

instead of

```
<data name="TestCalculation_TBox_TestCalculate.PlaceholderText" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Calculate value one</value>
</data>
```

(note the two dots in the the upper Code Sample)

I hope this will help someone in the future, as the given Errormessage is not very informative.

Edit: deleted Pastebin Debug output, as it has nothing to do with the solution.